# RegExp constructor properties input

Tags: javascript, regex, constructor, exec

Setting the global flag to true:

```
<script>
var str="I am really puzzled up";
var str1="Being puzzled is first step towards understanding";
var patt=new RegExp("puzzled","gi");
patt.exec(str);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //I am really puzzled up *[1]
patt.exec(str1);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //I am really puzzled up *[2]
patt.exec(str1);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //Being puzzled is first step towards understanding *[3]
</script>
```

Without setting the global flag to true:

```
<script>
var str="I am really puzzled up";
var str1="Being puzzled is first step towards understanding";
var patt=new RegExp("puzzled","i");
patt.exec(str);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //I am really puzzled up 
patt.exec(str1);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //Being puzzled is first step towards understanding  
</script>
```

The outputs have been shown by comments

- [1]-I am satisfied with this output
- [2]-Now when i have already matched the pattern with some other string constructor property is still showing me first matched string
- [3]-It is only by again matching the pattern with the string that i get the desired result.

Why would i have to use `patt.exec method` twice to change the update the result by constructor property?

Ques-It only happens when `global` flag of pattern is set to `true` .If global flag is not set the updation of result by constructor property happens the very first time.

Comment: `RegExp.$_` is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FDeprecated_Features#RegExp_Properties

Comment: Ok but it still shows me the output (not correct one) for global flag set... and shows correct for not global flag.

Comment: Sir on that page its written that they will be completely depreceated in future. At present they can be used

Comment: Deprecated means that you are advised to move away from it if you already use it in old code/not use it in new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How does `RegExp.exec` works?

When given a string, `RegExp.exec` will:

- If the pattern is global (has `g` flag), then it will use `lastIndex` property **in the `RegExp` *instance*** and search the string for the pattern from the index indicated. **This means that `RegExp.exec` is not aware of the input string**. It will just take the index as starting point and search the string, no matter whether the string is the same as the previous call or not.

  If a match is found, it will return an array with the match, and it also update the fields in the `RegExp` *instance* accordingly, as shown in the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). `lastIndex` will be updated with the position to start the next match.

  If a match is not found, it will reset the `lastIndex` to 0, and return `null` as result of calling `RegExp.exec`.
- If the pattern is not global (`g` flag not set), `lastIndex` property will be ignored. The match always starts from index 0 regardless of `lastIndex` property.

To be extremely clear:

- `RegExp` *instance* will store the position to start next match (`lastIndex`), the status of the flags (`global`, `multiline`, `ignorecase`) and the text of the pattern (`source`).
- The return value of `RegExp.exec` is an array that stores the result of the match. The array also have `input` property which stores the input string and `index` property which stores the 0-based index of the match.

### The `RegExp.$_` property of `RegExp` *object*

`RegExp.$_` property and several other similar properties on `RegExp` *object* [are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FDeprecated_Features#RegExp_Properties). Just access them via the array returned by `RegExp.exec`. `$_` is equivalent to the `input` property attached in the array returned by `RegExp.exec`.

```
var arr = pattern.exec(inputString);
if (arr !== null) {
    // Print to the console the whole input string that has a match
    console.log(arr.input); 
}
```

Since those properties are on the `RegExp` object, it is very confusing when you work with multiple `RegExp` instances - you don't know whether the properties are from the current or previous execution, such as in this case.

From the behavior that you get, it seems that `RegExp.$_` is modified when `RegExp.exec` found a match, and it will not be modified (previous value stay) when `RegExp.exec` fails to match.

### Explanation of the behavior

Please read the part above for full picture of how it works.

I added some comment on what happens behind the scene in your original code:

**Global flag**

```
var str="I am really puzzled up";
var str1="Being puzzled is first step towards understanding";

// Global pattern
var patt=new RegExp("puzzled","gi");

// From index 0 of str, found match at index 12
// RegExp.$_ is set to current input - str
// patt.lastIndex is set to index 19
patt.exec(str);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //I am really puzzled up *[1]

// From index 19 of str1, can't find any match
// Since no match is found, RegExp.$_'s value is not changed
// patt.lastIndex is set to 0
patt.exec(str1);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //I am really puzzled up *[2]

// Found index 0 of str1, found match at index 6
// RegExp.$_ is set to current input - str1
// patt.lastIndex is set to 13
patt.exec(str1);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //Being puzzled is first step towards understanding *[3]
```

**No global flag**

```
var str="I am really puzzled up";
var str1="Being puzzled is first step towards understanding";
// Not global
var patt=new RegExp("puzzled","i");

// From index 0 of str, found match at index 12
// RegExp.$_ is set to current input - str
patt.exec(str);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //I am really puzzled up

// From index 0 of str1, found match at index 6
// RegExp.$_ is set to current input - str1
patt.exec(str1);
alert(RegExp.$_);   //Being puzzled is first step towards understanding
```

Comment: I dont think there can be any better explanation than this..  Highly appreciable Sir.Well i think you should certainly get more useful answer points for this...