# Why jquery regular expression return different - different test cases each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I facing-out a problem when use Regexp for restrict to enter HTML entity into text-area.

I used this Regexp - `/<(.|\n)*?>/g;`  for restrict HTML entity and it's work fine for me, but when i declare the global variable and used this regexp, It's give me different - different test cases(true/false) each time.

There is a Jsfiddle - [Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/eZe3n/1/)

when you click on "submit" button first time you get "true" and second time you get "false" for same content.

Can any one tell me why my regexp return different - different test cases each time when declare it globally?

Thank for your help...!!!

Comment: You should never use anything like `(.|\n)` in your regexes; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2407870/20938) for the reasons why.  The traditional way to match anything-including-newlines in JavaScript is `[\s\S]`, but you can usually do better than that. In this case you could use `/<[^<>]+>/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `g` flag on the `RegExp` literal. The solution is to remove the `g` flag.

---

According to the documentation of [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) (emphasis mine):

> As with `exec` (or in combination with it), `test` **called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match**.

After the first call to `test`, the `lastIndex` property of the `RegExp` object `/<(.|\n)*?>/g` is updated. The index used as the offset for the second call to `test`. Since there is no more match for the pattern, the second call returns `false` and `lastIndex` is reset to 0. You can see the `lastIndex` property of the regex being changed in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eZe3n/2/).

Removing the `g` flag will cause the engine to ignore the `lastIndex` property.

I have described in detailed behaviour of `RegExp.exec` (which is also the same for `RegExp.text`) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579947/regexp-constructor-properties-input/16580881#16580881).

Answer (score 7):

This is because you're using the `g` flag on the RegExp.

If you need to use `g`, you can define your regexp inside the function so you get a fresh one each time

```
function CheckContent(){
  var RegForRestrictHtmlTags2 = /<(.|\n)*?>/g;  
  $('#txtJobDesc').val("AAAAAAAA<fff>AAAAAA");
  alert(RegForRestrictHtmlTags2.test($('#txtJobDesc').val()));
}
```

When using the `g` flag, you can use `.test` to find multiple occurrences within your subject string. `.test` will continue to return `true` for each unique match. Once `.test` return false, it will effectively "reset" to the starting position.

Consider this simple example

```
> var re = /a/g;
undefined

> var str = 'aaaaab';
undefined

> re.test(str); // first a
true

> re.test(str); // second a
true

> re.test(str); // third a
true

> re.test(str); // fourth a
true

> re.test(str); // fifth a
true

> re.test(str); // no more a's; reset
false

> re.test(str); // back to first a
true
```

Comment: One thing worth notice is that you can call `test` (with `g` flag) on different strings, and it will just chuck on ahead from the last recorded index.